# Script Detecting Variable as a Command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a shell script where I accept a username from the user and check if that specific user is present on the system. If so then change the password else display an error. At this stage I am just checking if the entered username exists and displaying a message accordingly.

This the code that I have written:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the username whose password needs to be reset: "
read UNAME
echo "You want to reset password for $uname"

awk -F':' '{print $1}' /etc/passwd > userlist.txt

FLAG = 0

for LINE in $(cat userlist.txt)
do
if [ "$UNAME" == "$LINE" ]
then
    FLAG = 1
    break
else
    FLAG = 0
fi
done

if[ "$FLAG" == 0 ]
then
    echo "User $UNAME does not exist"
else
    echo "Password for $UNAME can be reset"
fi
```

Problem here is that, for some reason, bash is treating my `FLAG` variable as a command.

Here is the output:

```
Enter the username whose password needs to be reset: 
abc
You want to reset password for 
./chpwd.sh: line 9: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
./chpwd.sh: line 18: FLAG: command not found
Password for abc can be reset
```

As you guys can see, its stuck up upon `FLAG` variable. I can not figure out why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in shell are set with the syntax `var=value` (or better, `var="value"`). That is, you cannot have spaces around `=`. That's why your script is complaining:

```
FLAG = 0
```

Is saying: run the command `FLAG` with the parameters `=` and `0`.

So what you want to write is:

```
FLAG=0
```

Also: Note reading the file can be improved. From:

```
for LINE in $(cat userlist.txt)
do
...
done
```

to

```
while IFS= read LINE
do
...
done < userlist.txt
```

Other things:

```
if[ "$FLAG" == 0 ]
```

needs spaces around `[` and `]`:

```
if [ "$FLAG" == 0 ]
```

and, in fact, if you are doing integer comparison you have to use `-eq` to see if the value is the same:

```
if [ "$FLAG" -eq 0 ]
```

Comment: Thank you @fedorqui ! Did the job for me. I am a newbie programmer. Your tips will help me a lot. The program did work with `if [ "$FLAG" == 0 ]` but yes I will definitely try the -eq feature.

Answer (score 0):

U can use simple script to find the specific username exist or not

```
    #!/bin/bash
    Read -p "enter ur username" uid
    Grep ^$uid /etc/passwd
    [ $? != 0 ] && eche -e "/033[31m i can see ur user!" || echo -e "/033[33m u can chang pass "
```

Plus u can use while for read /etc/passwd 
Like:

```
Read -p "enter uid for check " uid
IFS=":"
While read UID REST 
do
[ $UID -eq $uid ] && echo " user found you can change pass " break
Done </etc/passwd
```